# How to create a database in Datastore and add Multible tables in that database

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to use JDO for Datastore....Please provide any materials or tutorials other than google documents....

I need to know....How to create a database in Datastore and add Multible tables in that database and add properties and corresponding values to the properties.....

How to do this in Datastore....

Please help me....

Answer (score 1):

The [Storing Data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) section of the App Engine docs covers this in extensive detail. You should definitely read it thoroughly before looking elsewhere, as it covers all the basics. It also describes the structure of the datastore - including the fact that the datastore does not have a fixed schema - so it has no tables, and no fixed columns.